# how to set min an max width to anchor popup in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

```
if(anchorWidthFlag)  
   {  
     popUp.popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth = false;  
     popUp.explicitWidth = anchorWidth;         
   }
```

here AnchorWidthFlag = true  and anchorWidth = 350;

i tried this way

1) popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth = false
  2) explicitWidth = anchorWidth //350

but not get appropriate output.

I want to set minWidth and maxWidth to anchor popup, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set *popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth* to false and set *minWidth* and *maxWidth* on *dropDown* group. If I understood what you want, it would work.

Setting *minWidth/maxWidth* on popupAnchor woudn't make any effect due to the fact, that popup is not a child of popupAnchor. So standard flex measuring steps wouldn't work here. Though popup doesn't know parent *minWidth/maxWidth*. If you open the source code of PopUpAnchor you will see that if popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth is true the size of popup is set to explicit size of the popupAnchor, but there is no code about *minWidth/maxWidth*. If you really need to set these sizes on PopUpAnchor you would extend PopUpAnchor class and implement this functionality.

Comment: thank you to replay
but when i set minWidth and maxWidth then it's set to dropdown group instead of Anchor popup.